# casting template to child template

Tags: c++

I have class `A`, and it's extended by `B` class.
Then I have class Ptr - kind of smart pointer.
I need to statically cast `Ptr<A>` to `Ptr<B>`.

and all the time compiler gives me:

error: invalid static_cast from type `Ptr<A>` to type `Ptr<B>`

Comment: Why is this closed? No code illustration is required. Both the problem and the answer are very clear. Please, don't close questions just because you have failed to understand them, or because you don't know the subject matter well enough to answer. Move on to a more basic question that suits you better.

Comment: I also voted to re-open this question.

Answer (score 2):

That `Ptr<A>` and `Ptr<B>` were instantiated from the same class template `Ptr`, and their template arguments `A` and `B` are related, doesn't mean you can implicitly convert from `Ptr<A>` to `Ptr<B>` and/or back.

You have to create your own conversion operator:

```
template <typename T1>
struct Ptr
{
   // ...

   template <typename T2>
   operator Ptr<T2>()
   {
      return Ptr<T2>(/* ...? */);
   }

   // ...
};
```

However, I'd really suggest you don't do this and find some other way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `Ptr<A>` is a completely an other type then `Ptr<B>` even though A is derived from B.

Comment: That's not correct, you can use converting constructors and operators to make it valid.

Comment: And that's what I'd have said in my answer, had the question not been closed, preventing me from helping.